# Proper way of using Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

Here I have piece of code, showing example of how I want to update values in dictionary.
I do not think this is the best way, because I am not sure that it is thread safe.

Edit: it is just POC code, what I mean is getting Keys copied to array and then doing stuff on Dictionary. I can't post code of my employer here guys, so I made example to make point.

When I get copy of Keys to array, I might be using Dictionary reference in some other part of code, where some keys might be added, and then such function won't update all keys because I have copied those at some point of time. Should I subclass or maybe wrap dictionary and make operations on it with lock, or is there simplier way?

How should I update the values in a proper way?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
     Dictionary<string, int> dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();

     dic.Add("Kej1",0);
     dic.Add("Kej2",1);
     dic.Add("Kej3", 3);
     dic.Add("Kej4", 3);

     String[] arr = new string[dic.Count] ;
     dic.Keys.CopyTo(arr,0);

    foreach (var va in arr)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dic[va] + " " + va);
        dic[va] = 10;
        Console.WriteLine(dic[va] + " " + va);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: No idea what this example is supposed to show. You mention multiple threads, but the example has none. Try to reword your question.

Comment: This looks like a console application. You have no multiple threads in your code.

Comment: @Jon I have updated description, it is just POC code, some imagination would be apprecieted, I can't post here "not mine code".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current implementation is fine as it is. Your

```
 Dictionary<string, int> dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

is a local variable and it is only referenced by your main thread. You do not need to worry about thread-safty.

If you *really* want to make it thread-safe, then you can lock the dictionary this way:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
  Dictionary<string, int> dic = new Dictionary<string, int>(); 

  lock(dic)
  {
   dic.Add("Kej1",0); 
   dic.Add("Kej2",1); 
   dic.Add("Kej3", 3); 
   dic.Add("Kej4", 3); 

   String[] arr = new string[dic.Count] ; 
   dic.Keys.CopyTo(arr,0);

   foreach (var va in arr) 
   { 
     Console.WriteLine(dic[va] + " " + va); 
     dic[va] = 10; 
     Console.WriteLine(dic[va] + " " + va); 
   } 
  } 
  Console.ReadKey(); 
}
```

Comment: that was my first thought but I wanted to do it in possible best way, and for now it looks like it is.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a Thread Safe dictionary from .NET 4 onward you can use [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) .

Comment: yes you can but this has some *unexpected* behavior (add might not succeed for example) you have get used to - in most cases a normal Dictionary with `lock(dict) { ... }` does the job just fine

Comment: Will it allow me to update values of dictionary, like in example above, I can't update values without copying keys to array because of enumeration breaking? I will test some with concurrent dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to worry about thread safety if you actually use multiple threads. Most of the time you can't do that unknowingly. So just don't worry about it and access your dictionary any way you want.

If you use anything that has the word "async" or "Begin" in it, you might need to reconsider this.